# How to use 2 mediapipe models using react

Tags: reactjs, tensorflow.js, mediapipe

Im trying to parse video using 2 mediapipe models (FaceMesh and FaceDetection) however, I cannot find a way to draw landmarks from both models. I can see in console outputs from both `console.log(results)` but I can only see landmarks from model which is called second. So in this instance I can only see landmarks from `faceMesh`.
[image: Console output]

```
await faceDetection.send({ image: webcamRef.current.video });
await faceMesh.send({ image: webcamRef.current.video });
```

Here is my code:

```
import { FaceDetection } from '@mediapipe/face_detection';
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import * as cam from "@mediapipe/camera_utils";
import { drawConnectors, drawLandmarks, drawRectangle } from "@mediapipe/drawing_utils";
import Webcam from "react-webcam";
import { settings } from "./settings";

function App() {
  const [checkedSettings, setCheckedSettings] = useState(
    new Array(settings.length).fill(false)
  );

  const webcamRef = useRef(null);
  const canvasRef = useRef(null);
  const camera = useRef(null);

  const [state, setState] = useState(
    {gameOn: false}
  );

  const handleOnChange = (position) => {
    const updateCheckedSettings = checkedSettings.map((item, index) =>
      index === position ? !item : item
    );
    setCheckedSettings(updateCheckedSettings);
  };

  const startGame = () => {
    const faceMesh = new FaceMesh({
      locateFile: (file) => {
        return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_mesh/${file}`;
      },
    });


    faceMesh.setOptions({
      refineLandmarks: true,
      selfie: true,
      minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
      minTrackingConfidence: 0.5,
      maxNumFaces: 2,
    });

    const onResults = (results) => {
      const video = webcamRef.current.video;
      const videoWidth = video.videoWidth;
      const videoHeight = video.videoHeight;
  
      // Set canvas width
      canvasRef.current.width = videoWidth;
      canvasRef.current.height = videoHeight;
  
      const canvasElement = canvasRef.current;
      const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
      canvasCtx.save();
      canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
      canvasCtx.drawImage(
        results.image,
        0,
        0,
        canvasElement.width,
        canvasElement.height
      );
  
      if (results.multiFaceLandmarks) {
        for (const landmarks of results.multiFaceLandmarks) {
          settings.forEach((setting, index) => {
            if (setting.type === "connector" && checkedSettings[index]) {
              drawConnectors(canvasCtx, landmarks, setting.attribute, setting.style);
            } else if (setting.type === "landmark" && checkedSettings[index]) {
              drawLandmarks(canvasCtx, landmarks, setting.style);
            }
          });
          console.log(results)
        };
      };
      canvasCtx.restore();
    }
    
    faceMesh.onResults(onResults);

    const faceDetection = new FaceDetection(
      {locateFile: (file) => {
        return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/face_detection@0.4/${file}`;
      }});

      const faceDetectionOnResults = (results) => {
        const video = webcamRef.current.video;
        const videoWidth = video.videoWidth;
        const videoHeight = video.videoHeight;
    
        // Set canvas width
        canvasRef.current.width = videoWidth;
        canvasRef.current.height = videoHeight;
    
        const canvasElement = canvasRef.current;
        const canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext("2d");
        canvasCtx.save();
        canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, canvasElement.width, canvasElement.height);
        canvasCtx.drawImage(
          results.image,
          0,
          0,
          canvasElement.width,
          canvasElement.height
        );
        if (results.detections) {
          drawRectangle(
              canvasCtx, results.detections[0].boundingBox,
              {color: 'blue', lineWidth: 1, fillColor: '#00000000'});
        }
        canvasCtx.restore();
      }

    faceDetection.onResults(faceDetectionOnResults);

    faceDetection.setOptions({
      selfieMode: true,
      model: 'short',
      minDetectionConfidence: 0.5,
      minTrackingConfidence: 0.5,
      maxNumFaces: 2,
    });

    if (
      typeof webcamRef.current !== "undefined" &&
      webcamRef.current !== null
    ) {
      camera.current = new cam.Camera(webcamRef.current.video, {
        onFrame: async () => {
          await faceDetection.send({ image: webcamRef.current.video });
          await faceMesh.send({ image: webcamRef.current.video });
        },
        width: 1280,
        height: 720,
      });
      camera.current.start();
    }
    setState({ gameOn: true });
  };

  const stopGame = () => {
    camera.current.stop();
    setState({ gameOn: false });
  };

  const gameTrigger = () => {
    if (state.gameOn) {
      stopGame();
    } else {
      startGame();
    }
  };

  return (
    <center>
      <div className="App">
        {settings.map(({ name }, index) => {
          return (
            <li key={index} style={{
              position: "absolute",
              zindex: 9,
              top: 10+index*20,
            }}>
              <Webcam
         muted={true}
         ref={webcamRef}
         style={{
          width: "0%", height: "0%"
          }}
        />
        <canvas
          ref={canvasRef}
          className="output_canvas"
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            marginLeft: "auto",
            marginRight: "auto",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 640,
            textAlign: "center",
            zindex: 9,
            width: 1280,
            height: 720,
          }}
        ></canvas>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                id={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}
                name={name}
                value={name}
                checked={checkedSettings[index]}
                onChange={() => handleOnChange(index)}
              />
              <label htmlFor={`custom-checkbox-${index}`}>{name}</label>
            </li>
          )
        })}
        <button 
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          zindex: 20,
          top: 10,
          left: 10,
        }}
          onClick={gameTrigger}>{state.gameOn ? "Stop" : "Start"}</button>
      </div>
    </center>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Here is my settings.js file

```
import { 
    FACEMESH_RIGHT_EYE,
    FACEMESH_RIGHT_EYEBROW,
    FACEMESH_RIGHT_IRIS,
    FACEMESH_LEFT_EYE,
    FACEMESH_LEFT_EYEBROW,
    FACEMESH_LEFT_IRIS,
    FACEMESH_FACE_OVAL,
    FACEMESH_LIPS,
    FACEMESH_TESSELATION } from "@mediapipe/face_mesh";

export const settings = [
    {
      name: "1",
      style: {color: "#E0E0E0", lineWidth: 1},
      attribute: FACEMESH_TESSELATION,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "2",
        style: {color: "#FF3030"},
        attribute: FACEMESH_RIGHT_EYE,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "3",
        style: {color: "#FF3030"},
        attribute: FACEMESH_RIGHT_EYEBROW,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "4",
        style: {color: "#FF3030"},
        attribute: FACEMESH_RIGHT_IRIS,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "5",
        style: {color: "#30FF30"},
        attribute: FACEMESH_LEFT_EYE,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "6",
        style: {color: "#30FF30"},
        attribute: FACEMESH_LEFT_EYEBROW,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "7",
        style: {color: "#30FF30"},
        attribute: FACEMESH_LEFT_IRIS,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "8",
        style: {color: "#E0E0E0"},
        attribute: FACEMESH_FACE_OVAL,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "9",
        style: {color: "#E0E0E0"},
        attribute: FACEMESH_LIPS,
        type: "connector"},
    {
        name: "10",
        style: {color: "#BE36D4", lineWidth: 1, radius: 1},
        attribute: false,
        type: "landmark",
    },
  ];
```

Is there a way to parse my video using both models?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I fixed it by not drawing into canvas right away but instead I save the output from Face Detection into a variable and then draw it all at once.

Here is the code

```
if (results.multiFaceLandmarks) {
        for (const landmarks of results.multiFaceLandmarks) {
          settings.forEach((setting, index) => {
            if (setting.type === "connector" && checkedSettings[index]) {
              drawConnectors(canvasCtx, landmarks, setting.attribute, setting.style);
            } else if (setting.type === "landmark" && checkedSettings[index]) {
              drawLandmarks(canvasCtx, landmarks, setting.style);
            }
          });
        };
      };
      for (const faceDetection of faceDetectionArray) {
        drawRectangle(canvasCtx, faceDetection.boundingBox, {color: 'blue', lineWidth: 4, fillColor: '#00000000'});
      };
      canvasCtx.restore();
```

and

```
const faceDetectionOnResults = (results) => {
      if (results.detections) {
        faceDetectionArray = results.detections;
      }
    }
```

Comment: Amazing work getting the two models working. I've reproduced this locally but one model is inverted. When I move left it moves right. Have you noticed this? If so, did you find a solution?

Comment: Hey @zero_cool, I remember I had the same issue but I somehow fixed it. Looking back at my code I don't really see how :D https://github.com/aheldes/ml-webapp if you wish you can check my source code here :)